# Сохранить переменную с диалогового окна файла tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Доброго времени суток. Мне нужно с помощью button открывать файлы. А потом нужно работать с ними (конкретно - использовать имена уже для других целей)

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror

class MyFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Example")
        self.master.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S)

        self.button = Button(self, text="Browse", command=self.load_file, width=10)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

    def load_file(self):
        self.fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Temaplate files", "*.tplate"),
                                           ("HTML files", "*.html;*.htm"),
                                           ("All files", "*.*") ))
        if self.fname:
            try:
                print("""here it comes: self.settings["template"].set(fname)""")
            except:                     # <- naked except is a bad idea
                showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read file\n'%s'" % self.fname)
            return 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyFrame().mainloop()
```

Как сделать чтобы значения fname записать в обычный массив и потом уже использовать по-своему?

Comment: У вас после `self.fname = ...` в `self.fname` записано имя выбранного файла (или пустая строка, если нажата отмена). Ниже в этом же методе уже можно как угодно это значение использовать.

Comment: А как-то из другого метода можно? Просто хотелось бы еще одну кнопку добавить, которая бы запускала "некий" процесс, используя как раз этот массив и работая с ним.

Comment: Легко. Добавляете еще одну кнопку, прикрепляете к ней обработчик, в нем обращаетесь к `self.fname`, только не забудьте проверить, что там не пустое значение.

Comment: как раз-таки я и пробовал так. пишет, что такой переменной нет

Comment: знаете, я вас обманул. сейчас, все магическим образом заработало! спасибо!

Comment: Добавьте ответом, если разобрались. Мне на самом деле просто лениво было давать вам готовый ответ)

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror

class MyFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Example")
        self.master.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S)

        self.button = Button(self, text="Browse", command=self.load_file, width=10)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.button = Button(self, text="Browse", command=self.start, width=10)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

    def load_file(self):
        self.fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Temaplate files", "*.tplate"),
                                           ("HTML files", "*.html;*.htm"),
                                           ("All files", "*.*") ))
        if self.fname:
            try:
                print("""here it comes: self.settings["template"].set(fname)""")
            except:                     # <- naked except is a bad idea
                showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read file\n'%s'" % self.fname)
            return 

    def start(self):
        print("it's work!", self.fname)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyFrame().mainloop()
```

Comment: ну, соответственно, в start() нужно еще проверку отправить